# How to allow two instances of an user to run in local host

Tags: angularjs, node.js, localhost

I'm new to scripting. I've tried developing an application using angular & node. For the purpose of saving data, I've used JSON files using http requests instead of database connectivity.

I wanted to know how to access the same user at two different instances and how to sync the data available in both the instances??

Thanks in advance...